# Use SQL Statement to ignore weekends in Microsoft Acess

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

I have found several topics on how to use an SQL statement to ignore weekends.  I don't need to ignore holidays, just weekends.  However, none of these seem to work for me.  I am using an Access database within asp.net and have tried using this function:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, DateCalled) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

but the AccessDataSource doesn't seem to like that syntax.  My actual query needs to search for records that are 3 business days old, meaning that if there is a record on a Friday, it would not show up until the following Wednesday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a Date/Time parameter, *DATEFIRST*, and you want to select rows whose  *DateCalled* values are no more recent than 3 workdays before *DATEFIRST*.  I interpret that to mean these are the most recent dates you want for each parameter value ...

```
DATEFIRST         3 workdays previous
---------------   -------------------
Mon, 01/28/2013   Wed, 01/23/2013
Tue, 01/29/2013   Thu, 01/24/2013
Wed, 01/30/2013   Fri, 01/25/2013
Thu, 01/31/2013   Mon, 01/28/2013
Fri, 02/01/2013   Tue, 01/29/2013
Sat, 02/02/2013   Tue, 01/29/2013
Sun, 02/03/2013   Tue, 01/29/2013
```

I tested the following query with Access 2007.  It returns results which match the above DATEFIRST pattern.

```sql
PARAMETERS DATEFIRST DateTime;
SELECT *
FROM your_table AS y
WHERE y.DateCalled < DateAdd(
        'd',
        Switch(
            Weekday([DATEFIRST])=1,-4,
            Weekday([DATEFIRST])=2,-4,
            Weekday([DATEFIRST])=3,-4,
            Weekday([DATEFIRST])=4,-4,
            Weekday([DATEFIRST])=5,-2,
            Weekday([DATEFIRST])=6,-2,
            Weekday([DATEFIRST])=7,-3
            ),
        [DATEFIRST]
        );
```

Based on your comments, I suspect I misunderstood your intention.  It seems you don't want a parameter query.  Instead you want the `DateCalled` filter to be 3 days before the date the query is run.  If so, discard the `PARAMETERS` clause and substitute Access' `Date()` function for `[DATEFIRST]`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM your_table AS y
WHERE y.DateCalled < DateAdd(
        'd',
        Switch(
            Weekday(Date())=1,-4,
            Weekday(Date())=2,-4,
            Weekday(Date())=3,-4,
            Weekday(Date())=4,-4,
            Weekday(Date())=5,-2,
            Weekday(Date())=6,-2,
            Weekday(Date())=7,-3
            ),
        Date()
        );
```

Comment: Ok, yes, this is what I was looking for! Only problem I'm having is that when attemtping to execute this query, I receive an error stating that "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Comment: Use that SQL as a new query in Access.  When you attempt to run it, Access will display a parameter dialog to request a value for each missing parameter, and the dialog will include the "name" of the missing parameter.  What is it that Access thinks is a parameter?  If you misspelled a field or table name, Access won't find it so will conclude it must be a parameter.  Did you include the quotes around `d` (`'d'`)?  `DateAdd` expects a string value for the first argument.

Comment: Access popped up with a dialog for DATEFIRST

Comment: But DATEFIRST is designed to be a parameter, which means you have to supply a value when you run the query.  If you didn't actually want a parameter, what did you want instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, I need to  have a grid view show all records that are greater than or equal to 3 business days old, excluding weekends. Your example with the actual dates above is what I am looking for. Does that clear anything up? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Would the DATEFIRST parameter be equivalent to the Now() function?

Comment: `Now()` includes the current time as well as date.  Perhaps you want the `Date()` function instead.  If you discard the `PARAMETERS` clause and substitute `Date()` for `[DATEFIRST]` in that SQL, it will return rows whose `DateCalled` values are no later than 3 workdays before the date when the query is run.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm looking to display records that are at least 3 days old, excluding weekends.  So, for example, if a record's DateCalled is on a Friday, that record would not pop up until Wednesday of the next week because that would be 3 business days from the date that the record was created. So, using your SQL Statement, I have come up with this so far:

Comment: DateCalled <= DateAdd(
        'd',
        Switch(
            Weekday(DateCalled)=1,-4,
            Weekday(DateCalled)=2,-4,
            Weekday(DateCalled)=3,-4,
            Weekday(DateCalled)=4,-4,
            Weekday(DateCalled)=5,-2,
            Weekday(DateCalled)=6,-2,
            Weekday(DateCalled)=7,-3
            ),
        Date()
        );

Comment: In your layout of "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" What is "1"? Sunday?

Comment: I believe your suggestion is what I need.  I am currently testing out the SQL statement now, and believe it should work correctly.  However, if Sunday is 1, Monay is 2, etc. I have changed the switched values to 1, -3...... 2, -3....... 3, -3...... 4, -5.......5, -5.......6, -6.......7, -4.  Should that work correctly? because if the record date is on a Sunday, 3 business days later is Wendesday.  If it's on a Wednesday, 3 business days later would be the following Monday. If it's on a Saturday, 3 business days later would be Wednesday. correct?

Comment: I approached it from the opposite direction.  When you run the query on a Mon., you want the previous Wed. as the most recent DateCalled.  That Wed. is 5 days before Mon., so you want DateCalled *less than* Date() - 4.  I used similar logic to create the table in the first part of my answer, using the DATEFIRST parameter version of the query.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean.  Will the numbers I posted do the same thing? Thanks so much for your help by the way!

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  It was challenging for me to keep track of the correct number of days offset from the reference date, and I really don't want to do that again.  ;-)

Comment: :) No problem, either way, thanks to you I'm on the right track!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`weekday`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/weekday.php):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE weekday(date) NOT IN (1, 7)
```

Comment: Unless you specify differently in access Sunday is the first day of the week, and the numbering starts at 1, so you would need `NOT IN (1, 7)`, or `WEEKDAY(date, 7) NOT IN (1, 2)`

Comment: Ok! That syntax will find all records correctly! Now, how would I go about searching for records that are 3 days old, and ignore weekends?

Comment: @EricHickman, the rule is one question per "thread" comments are not for new questions. sorry.

Comment: @EricHickman Have a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272320/number-of-columns-in-ms-access-2010 for some notes.

Comment: Technically, it's not a new question. I had stated that those were my requirements in my question.